# shell , introduce character between word with regex

Tags: regex, shell

I have words like TASK1 , TASK2 , TASK3 etc and I want to introduce a character "-" between TASK and number to get output like TASK-1 , TASK-2 , TASK-3 etc
How do i do that,? help please. thanks

Comment: [Replace `(\D+)(\d+)` with `\1-\2`](https://regex101.com/r/Wy7Xe0/1)

Comment: thanks. i will try.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have tagged `shell`, I hope you have tools like `sed` at your disposal. I would do it like below

```
echo "TASK123" | sed -E 's/TASK([[:digit:]]+)/TASK-\1/g'
TASK-123
```

Comment: the TASK could be any char example  JIRA-1898 , PLAT-1898 or WB-1999 , I tried 's/[A-z]+([[:digit:]]+)/(A-z)-\1/g' , but getting  this : (A-z)-123 , i want to group.